# python AttributeError: module 'socks' has no attribute 'setdefaultproxy'

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, proxy, python-import

Trying to test out the socks module but in every case I get an "AttributeError: module 'socks' has no attribute 'setdefaultproxy'"

```
  import socks
  import socket
  socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
  socket.socket = socks.socksocket
  import urllib2

  print(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.yahoo.com").read())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey there trying replacing

```
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
```

with

```
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
```

Note the below.

```
socks.set_default_proxy
```

In other words in should be

```
import socks
import socket
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
import urllib2

print(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.yahoo.com").read())
```

If it still failes try to check.
Which version of socks are you using?, Which version of python are you using?, because I tested it on python 2.7.9, and I don't get your error. Which os are you running?

```
sock: 1.5.6
```

https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks

http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks Joel that did the trick. As for the record I was running it on a python 3.5 on a Windows 7.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
socks.set_default_proxy(----)
```